# Is there a limit on character length for app groups in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, onesignal

When installing OneSignal into my Xcode iOS project, one instruction (to get badges to work) is to add an app group called "group.{{YOUR BUNDLE ID}}.onesignal". When I do that, the whole thing types in fine, but when it's shown, the last "l" is cut off.

It's unclear whether this cutoff is just a visual thing on display, or if it was truly cut off. Again, the "l" typed in fine.

Badges aren't working for me currently so I'm trying to figure out if this might be the problem. Is there anywhere I can check to see the app group's name, other than this UI?

[image]

Comment: AppStore Connect should have the actual app group but it is probably but a cosmetic cut off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode is probably just not showing the full App Group id on that tab.

The enabled App Group ids (the ones where the check box is turned on) are stored in your app's entitlements file, which is a source file you can find in the Xcode project navigator. Check that file to make sure your App Group id is correct.

For example, here's the app settings Signing & Capability tab, showing an App Group id that's been truncated:

[image: Signing & Capability tab showing the App Group id "group.com.dqd.very.extremely.ridiculously"]

And here is the app's entitlements file, which Xcode edits as a property list:

[image: Xcode property list editor showing the app entitlements file, containing the full id "group.com.dqd.very.extremely.ridiculously.tediously.unconscionable.hilariously.verbose.loquacious.sesquipedalian.groupname"]

Comment: Thanks @Rob mayoff, found that and see that it's just a visual cutoff.  The full version is in the entitlements file. Thank you!

Comment: Love the group name too!